# JSP could not find available java class

Tags: java, jsp

I used following code to call the java class from the JSP page.

```
<%String something=com.Package1.PrintInPicture.workingFunction(recentData);%>
```

I have package named as "com.Package1" as well as class and method named as "PrintInPicture" and "workingFunction(Stirng data)" respectively in that package. This is shown in code below:

```
    package com.package1;

    public class PrintInPicture {
    static int width, height;

    public static String workingFunction(String img_name) throws IOException{
}
```

But my JSP page is showing following error in the code which I have shown above:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: class PrintInPicture
location: package com.Package1
```

Please, Help me to solve this error.

Comment: ignoring the horrible scriptlet code, you have a typo: `com.package1.PrintInPicture`

Comment: Thanks dude.... you made my day... :)